# Why is Enumeration Name property not working?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that i want to display the connection strings of a database

```
Import-Module SqlServer
$AS = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$AS.connect("server1")
```

Now if i use the `FindByName()` property

```
$db = $AS.Databases.FindByName("database1")
$db.DataSources[0].ConnectionString
```

I get back the connection string successfully

however if i use Enumerator

```
foreach ($db in $AS.Databases.GetEnumerator())
{ $dbName = $db.Name
  $dbName
  $dbName.DataSources[0].ConnectionString
}
```

I get back the database name along with error/exception (because it couldnt get connection string for some reason):

> database1
>
> Cannot index into a null array.
>
> database2
>
> Cannot index into a null array.

I tried the following also:

```
$database1 = "database1"
$database1.DataSources[0].ConnectionString
```

and i also get back the same exception

So why is it that only FindByName works?

for additional info, this is what GetEnumerator lists:

```
$AS.Databases.GetEnumerator()
```

[image: enumerator output]

but also `$AS.Databases`

outputs the same thing...so whats even the point of the enumerator?

```
gm -i $AS.Databases
```

[image: gmdb]

```
gm -i $AS.Databases..GetEnumerator()
```

[image: gmenu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of what you're seeing is PowerShell's handling of (some) enumerables. Many (most?) are unrolled by PowerShell automatically, so the call to `.GetEnumerator()` isn't needed.

That's what's happening in your last example, looking at `$AS.Databases` vs `$AS.Databases.GetEnumerator()`. But it's only because you sent it out to the pipeline in that case; it's the display process that did the unrolling (in both cases).

If you did `gm -i $AS.Databases` vs `gm -i $AS.Databases.GetEnumerator()` you're going to see the difference; same if you assigned each of those to a variable and tried to call methods on them.

But back to using `foreach` it should again be redundant: `foreach ($db in $AS.Databases)` *should* work the same as `foreach ($db in $AS.Databases.GetEnumerator())` but I don't have this type in my env right now to test that.

So back to the issue at hand inside the `foreach`, I suggest you start checking types again. Compare:

```
$db = $Analysis_Server.Databases.FindByName("database1")
gm -i $db
```

to

```
foreach ($db in $AS.Databases.GetEnumerator())
{ 
    gm -i $db
    break
}
```

You might find the types aren't what you think.

This is especially true because you're using dot `.` notation, because PowerShell has *another* array shortcut built-in since version 3, whereby you can use `.` on an array of types, to return an array of the `.Property` of each item. For example:

```
$p = Get-Process chrome  # choose your own adventure
$p.Count
$p[0].Name
$p.Name
```

So a property you thought you were accessing on a single object, may have been on an array of objects, and may have been returning an array (or a single object), and handing that in the `foreach` may have returned a different quantity, or something, resulting in your attempt to index into what used to be an array, no longer work.

But again it's speculation on my part because *I* don't have those objects. Hopefully this helps you dig deeper into it though.

Comment: interesting. thanks for the breakdown! So this may be a case of the variable being set to an array and not actually a value. but then why wouldnt $database1 = "database1" this in my post have worked either? i am explicitly setting it to one string/name value, so it shouldnt have an issue...i also trie dthis just now: $db = $Analysis_Server.Databases.Name[1]         $db.DataSources[0].ConnectionString and it gave me the same exception

Comment: @Cataster I wish I could say for sure but I can't see the objects! Start testing with `gm -i $obj` (don't use `$obj | gm` in this case because that will obscure the enumerable thing),and start at the base objects before you start adding dot `.` operators. It might take a little doing to get to the bottom of it unfortunately.

Comment: That means that the property `.Databases` doesn't exist. PowerShell doesn't throw an exception on `$validObject.InvalidMember`, only on `$invalidObject.AnyMember`, so `.Databases` is `$null`, and so not valid for any further `.Member` access, and not valid for input into `gm`. That's why it's so important to see what `$AS` really is, start at the top with `gm -i $AS`.

Comment: woops looks like it was AD in your post by mistake. should be AS, that was the reason. now gm -i $AS.Databases.GetEnumerator() displayed this: Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
MoveNext    Method     bool MoveNext(), bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
Reset       Method     void Reset(), void IEnumerator.Reset()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
Current     Property   System.Object Current {get;}

Comment: gm -i $AS.Databases displayed the following Name property (i truncated the methods and other column because in the comments it gets cobbled up): Name
----
CollectionChanged
CollectionChanging
Add
BlockOnDemandLoad
CanAdd
Clear
Contains
ContainsName
CopyTo
Equals
Find
FindByName
GetByName
GetEnumerator
GetHashCode
GetNewID
GetNewName
GetType
IndexOf
IndexOfName
Insert
IsValidID
IsValidName
Move
Remove
RemoveAt
ToString
Item
Count
IsFixedSize
IsReadOnly
IsSynchronized
Loaded
Parent
SyncRoot

Comment: Updated the `$AD` thing. Hard to read that in a comment, but keep going down the chain, and check both the findbyname and foreach versions. You should find something useful following it all.

Comment: ill post a picture of the gm display of each in my post

Comment: posted a picture

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell does its own enumerating.

This done the trick!

```
foreach ($db in $AS.Databases){
  Write-Hst $db.Name -Fore green
  $db.DataSources | ForEach-Object{$_.ConnectionString}
}
```

Comment: @briantist figured out :D